# firebase database specific field updating multiple location

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

```
var updates = {};
updates['article/' + keyval] = new_sub_tag1;
updates['sub_tags/' + tagname] = new_sub_tag2;
ref.update(updates);
```

The above code is completely replacing the all of the elements with new one.

For now, I am using below code which is updating the particular field rather than overriding.

```
ref.child('article/' + keyval).update ({
     sub_tag: sub_tag_name
});
```

Instead I am looking for one particular field update at multiple locations in transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When updating multiple lower-level locations, be sure to have the *entire path* to the location you want to update in the left-hand side of the updates map:

```
var updates = {};
updates['article/' + keyval + '/property'] = new_sub_tag1_value;
updates['sub_tags/' + tagname + '/property'] = new_sub_tag2_value;
ref.update(updates);
```

Comment: Awesome...Thank you frank :)